wrong output for format.date
I´m trying to update an old simple extension, which has a date-field (type "date" in database). Dates are saved like "2024-09-05" in the database.
In the fluid template, i have something like:
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{foo.startdate}</f:format.date>
I works fine (output like 05.09.2024) in TYPO3 11, but in TYPO3 12 outout is 01.01.1970 for all dates.
Has anyone an idea what to do?
Thanks!

Did you check the raw content of {foo.startdate}, 01.01.1970 is the date you will get from an empty string or 0 or null.

check in the Installtool -> Update -> TCA Migration for migration of datetime fields. Of course you should migrate other things too perhaps. It's not done automatically by that tool, but it shows what you should adjust.

@cybot: that leads to an error: Exception: Cannot cast object of type "DateTime" to string

@David: thanks for the hint! A quick view doesn´t show any entries which are in connection with the date. But I'll working my way through it.

Hint: since v9 there's no need to define management columns (like starttime) in any ext_tables.sql file anymore: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.3/Feature-85160-AutoCreateManagementDBFieldsFromTCACtrl.html

@Julian Hofmann: Thanks for the hint. I need additional fields for the startdate/enddate. But it helps me solving the problem (see below)

That solves my problem:

Change fieldtype of startdate from date to int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
Convert values from date (2024-09-07) to timestamp
Update TCA for that field

like that:
'startdate' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:myextension.startdate',
   'config' => [
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'default' => 0,
        'behaviour' => [
            'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
        ],
    ],
],

You can use "Select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startdate), uid FROM mytable;" to get the timestamp values, than use that data to update the values: "Update mytable SET startdate=1529186411 WHERE uid =123;". There might be a better way to do that!

Did you try telling TCA that the MySQL field is a date field dbType=date?
https://docs.typo3.org/p/contentblocks/content-blocks/main/en-us/YamlReference/FieldTypes/DateTime/Index.html#confval-datetime-dbtype
I would try to stay with MySQL field type date instead of timestamp.

@Cybot: yes, that was the initial state. But leads to problems (but the extension is quite old)
